# From Developer to Web Developer to Web Designer

Tags: java, web-applications

Is it possible for a fairly experienced Java Developer to transition to being a Web Developer and then to Web Designer. I guess what I'm asking is - assume you have (Java) developer of above average aptitute - is it possible for that developer to acquire web development skills that will enable him/her to develop small business websites without the need to hire outside skills.
If so, where does one start on the path to becoming a Web Developer/Designer?
Skills required?
Tools used?

Comment: @leftbrainlogic: Photoshop or Gimp (Photoshop *is* better, but I'm using Gimp on Linux), CSS, HTML, Servlet, JSP, Selenium, Firefox's firebug... You're good to go :)   Note that as a Java developer you have a *huge* advantage over "simpler" Web designers: you can write real Java apps using GWT that shall convert them automatically to Javascript (think GMail: it's written in Java...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most web designers that I've met do not have a background in development at all. They possess a combination of aesthetic talent and an understanding of the HCI/usability side of website design.

They have some knowledge of what is possible of the development side or what the costs would be, but they usually don't do it themselves. A lot of studios have both designers and developers.

I personally believe that programming skills and design skills are not something that one can acquire, one has to have an aptitude and natural talent for each. It is possible to learn, but one wouldn't be as effective in it as a "natural". I freely admit, for example, that I do not have the aesthetic talent for good website design. Heck, my wife would argue that I don't have the aesthetic talent to dress myself nicely :) But if you have it, why not?

Beyond that, I would say that every developer should probably learn some of the state-of-the-art knowledge on ui or website design, or at least read a usability book. Jakob Nielsen writes some very good books on that topic.

A transition from non-web development to web development is generally easier, though you may have to learn a bunch of new APIs and possibly languages. For instance, I'm rusty on JSP and J2EE, and haven't learned any of the frameworks for the past 5-10 years.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is certainly possible, I assume you have been developing most Desktop Application and native Software using Java and so would advise to take up some JSP and Servlets knowledge to dive into web development.

1. [Books for Web Application
   Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214509/books-for-web-application-development)
2. [JSPs and Servlet - Head First Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005407) is good book to start.
3. [Don't Make me thing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107) good book on understanding UI stuffs, which is important for Web Designers.

Try to browse through web-development tags as you will find very useful suggestions there.

Answer (score 2):

While I think that it's definitely possible to transition from a Java Developer to a Web Developer, Web Design requires IMO a very different set of skills (including artistic sense) that some people don't have and might never be able to get.

Comment: Downvoting without any explanation is so lovely... And I really wonder why this answer is worth a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and as far as just moving to Web Developer, it isn't that difficult.  Pick up [Head First Servlets & JSP](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/) and give it a read to get up to speed on the stateless Request Response model and how things are done in the Java world.  The use of Jquery and other javascript frameworks has really made the javascript aspect much easier.  You don't have to learn as many browser specific tricks.

As far as web designer, Pascal is right on. That moves more into the artistic/graphic design world that is harder to do if you don't have that kind of design aesthetic.  But like most things, the best way to do it, is just to start doing it.  Create some small database driven sites on your own and get your feet wet.

Answer (score 1):

I think in Web development or any other development platform ,main programming skills are still valid. Only you have to learn new platform and new tools. Bu Web design, User experience 
is an other science and you should spend time to learn and practice.

And with passion and practicing it, I think you can be succesful on Web design or any other subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn a lot just by being around and working with designers. The more I work around designers the more I pick up subtle tricks and ways to look and and view a design. I think my design skills are much improved and I can improve my 'designs' by applying what I've noticed but I still don't think I have a natural *vision* for design.

Answer (score 0):

It surely is possible, but don't overestimate yourself, Web Designer is a totally other profession than developer. I doubt you can be a specialist in everything, and hiring a designer allows you to concentrate and be proficient on your skill set and allows you to have time to develop your business (which in turn will pay for outsourcing to a designer).